# $x^3+y^4=7$ has no integer solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove that $x^3+y^4=7$ has no integer solutions, but i have no idea how to start, please helps. I have tried to consider mod 7 to restrict the number of possible $x^3$ because $x^3 \equiv -1,0,1 \pmod{7}$, but it is not working.

Comment: I would try reducing mod some other numbers (not necessarily primes). 7 is not going to work.

Comment: if there's a solution then x must be negative.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131186/no-integer-solutions-and-congruences

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Consider the equation modulo $13$.  Then $x^3$ can be $0,1,5,8,12$ and $y^4$ can be $0,1,3,9$.  None of these add to $7$ modulo $13$.

I chose $13$ because $3|\phi(13)$ and $4|\phi(13)$, so I could get restrictions on both $x^3$ and $y^4$.

Comment: Why should we in general consider multiples of $\phi(n)$? Is there some kind of theory behind this? What does guarantee me that if I consider all remainders of $x^k$ modulo $n$ where $k \mid \phi(n)$ the variety won't be that big?

Comment: Well, the principle is that you want $\mathrm{gcd}(k,\phi(n))$ to be large relative to $\phi(n)$.  To avoid complicating things, let's take the case when $n$ is prime.  Then we know that there are $\mathrm{gcd}(n-1,k)$ solutions to $x^k \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$ and hence only $1 + \frac{n-1}{\mathrm{gcd}(n-1,k)}$ different values that $x^k$ can take modulo $n$.

Comment: Why there are exactly $gcd(n-1,k)$ solutions to the modulo equation? I fail to see this.

Comment: For prime $n$, take a primitive root $q$ modulo $n$.  Then $q^{s\frac{n-1}{\mathrm{gcd}(n-1,k)}}$ is a solution by Fermat's little theorem, and these are different for $0\leq s < \mathrm{gcd}(n-1,k)$ since $q$ is a primitive root.

Comment: And now that we know that $x^k \equiv 1$ (mod $n$) has $gcd(n-1, k)$ different solutions how can we tell that $x^k$ would take $1 + \frac{n-1}{gcd(n-1, k)}$ different values? Can't make the connection.

Comment: If $x$ is a solution to $x^k\equiv m\pmod{n}$ and $y^k \equiv 1\pmod{n}$, then $xy$ also satisfies $(xy)^k \equiv m\pmod{n}$.  So each such equation (other than $m=0$, which has one solution) that has a solution has $\mathrm{gcd}(n-1, k)$ solutions modulo $n$.  Divide $n-1$ by this to get the number of values $m \neq 0$ modulo $n$ that $x^k$ can take.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification!! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

universalset's answer is right, in these problems a useful heuristic is to find a number that produces remainders such that both sides cannot become equal. Here is a short Python program to find such numbers for this problem.

```
for m in range(2,100): #We hope to find such number less than 100
    a= set([x**3%m for x in range(0,1000)]) #Hoping remainders will cycle somewhere less that 1000 
    b= set([y**4%m for y in range(0,1000)]) #Hoping remainders will cycle somewhere less that 1000 

    flag = 0;
    for x in a:
        if (7%m+x%m)%m in b:
            flag=1;
            break;

    if flag==0:
        print (m,a,b)
```