# Is $7k-9$ ever a power of $2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I wonder if $7k-9$ is ever a power of $2$.

My work so far: if $k=2$, then $7k-9 > 4$. Then I checked if $7k-9$ is ever divisible by $4$. For $k=3$ it indeed is. For $k=4, 7k-9 > 16$. So I checked if $7k-9$ is ever divisible by $16$ and for $k= 15$ it indeed is. I could go on and try with $32$ but I don't feel inclined to do so. Is there any simpler method how to determine if $7k-9$ is ever a power of $2$?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We need $\displaystyle 2^a=7k-9$ for some integer $a\ge0$

$\displaystyle\implies 2^a\equiv-2\pmod7$

But $2^1\equiv2,2^2\equiv4\equiv-3,2^3\equiv1\pmod7$

Comment: But doesn't $2^a \equiv -2 \pmod 7$ imply that $2^a+2$ is divisible by 7?

Comment: @AhaanRungta, thanks. But, I don't subscribe to 'always':)

Comment: @Adam, yes, what's your confusion ?

Comment: So, since $7k-9 \equiv -2 \pmod 2$ then if $2^a = 7k-9$ then $2^a$ will also be congruent $-2 \pmod 7$, right?

Comment: @Adam, $$7k-9\equiv-2\pmod7$$

Comment: How can we see that (apart from trying a few ks)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11913/discussion-between-lab-bhattacharjee-and-adam)

Comment: @labbhattacharjee OK, true. Not always. But almost always.

Comment: @AhaanRungta, agreed. Here the modulus was obvious unlike here  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583126/x3y4-7-has-no-integer-solutions

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** $\ $ If so, $\rm\ mod\ 7\!:\ \color{#C00}2^n \equiv \color{#0A0}{-2}\ \overset{cubing}\Rightarrow \color{#C00}1 \equiv \color{#0A0}{-1}\ \Rightarrow\Leftarrow$

Comment: wow, impressive