# does $a^2-51b^2=\mp 6$ have a solution for integers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

does $a^2-51b^2=\mp 6$ have a solution for integers?

I have tried for many modulos, but could not get much out of them.

Comment: Are you familiar with quadratic residues?

Comment: yes. would mod 5 work?

Comment: The key, incidentally, is to pick a modulus that simplifies the problem; since $51=3\cdot17$, those are the places to start.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603104/is-7k-9-ever-a-power-of-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A solution to $a^2 - 51 b^2 = \pm 6$ would in particular be a solution to the congruence

$$a^2 \equiv \pm 6 \pmod{17}.$$

But neither $6$ nor $11$ is a quadratic residue modulo $17$ - the quadratic residues are $1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16$, so there is no solution.

Comment: beat me to it! :)

Answer (score 1):

$\rm mod\ 17\!:\ a^2\!\equiv \pm 6\Rightarrow a^4\!\equiv 6^2\!\equiv  2\Rightarrow a^8\!\equiv 4\Rightarrow a^{16}\!\equiv -1\,$ contra little Fermat. $\ $ **QED**