# Solve $7x^3+2=y^3$ over integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need to solve the following

solve  $7 x^3 + 2 = y^3$ over integers.
How can I do that?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603104/is-7k-9-ever-a-power-of-2

Answer (score 14):

To solve this kind of equations, we have several 'tools' such as

using mod, using inequalities, using factorization...

In your question, **using mod** will help you.

Since we have
$$y^3-2=7x^3,$$
the following has to be satisfied :
$$y^3\equiv 2\ \ \ (\text{mod $7$}).$$

However, in mod $7$, 
$$0^3\equiv 0,$$
$$1^3\equiv 1,$$
$$2^3\equiv 1,$$
$$3^3\equiv 6,$$
$$4^3\equiv 1,$$
$$5^3\equiv 6,$$
$$6^3\equiv 6.$$

So, there is no integer $y$ such that $y^3\equiv 2\ \ \ (\text{mod $7$}).$

Hence, we know that there is no solution.

Comment: Maybe an overkill, but for laziness: by FLT $y^6\equiv 1 \implies y^3\equiv\pm 1 \pmod 7$

Comment: A good point. Thanks.

Comment: @chubakueno for a brief moment, i thought the L stood for last...